# De-referencing a JavaScript property from inside an array

Tags: javascript, reference, dereference

I'm trying to de-reference a property on a JavaScript object, but am not getting the expected result.

I have an array of Knockout view-models (I don't think the problem is Knockout-specific), each of which has an observable, `Selected`. I add a subscription to this observable so that a function, `crossSelectTargetLangs` is called when the value of `Selected` is changed.

Furthermore, I add this subscription inside a `for...` loop.

```
var tl = 0,
    tlMax = allLangVMs.length,
    vmLang,
    selectedCode;

// for each 'vmLang' view-model in the 'allLangVMs' array...
for (; tl < tlMax; tl++) {

    // local variable for the context view-model    
    vmLang = allLangVMs[tl];

    // add the subscription to this observable    
    vmLang.Selected.subscribe(function() {

        // de-reference the vmLang.Code property
        selectedCode = (function(code) {
            return code;
        }(vmLang.Code));

        // pass the de-ref'd value to the target function    
        crossSelectTargetLangs(selectedCode);
    });
}
```

However, regardless of which view-model had its `Selected` observable updated, the argument passed to the target function is always the `Code` from the last element in the array, *i.e.* it doesn't appear to be de-referencing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are making dereferencing in a wrong place.
The code should look like this:

```js
var tl = 0,
    tlMax = allLangVMs.length,
    vmLang,
    selectedCode;

// for each 'vmLang' view-model in the 'allLangVMs' array...
for (; tl < tlMax; tl++) {

    // local variable for the context view-model    
    vmLang = allLangVMs[tl];

    (function(vmLangParam) {   
      vmLangParam.Selected.subscribe(function() {   
          crossSelectTargetLangs(vmLangParam.Code);
      });
    })(vmLang);
    
}
```